# Using jq to parse json key and value to CSV

Tags: json, export-to-csv, jq

I am a newbie to `jq` and is very excited to use it. What ever i am trying to achieve is possible with python but the intention is to learn `jq`.I am trying to process JSON out of a curl command.

Below is the response of my `curl` command

```
{
    "results": [{
            "name": "smith Jones",
            "DOB": "1992-03-26",
            "Enrollmentdate": "2013-08-24"

        },

        {
            "name": "Jacob Mathew",
            "DOB": "1993-03-26",
            "Enrollmentdate": "2014-10-02"
        },

        {
            "name": "Anita Rodrigues",
            "DOB": "1994-03-26",
            "Enrollmentdate": "2015-02-19"
        }
    ]
}
```

I was able to get the desired output to some extent. But i am unable to print the key itself in the output. I need this information to use it at a later time as a header of the column when i export this csv file (file.csv) into excel. I am planning to write a bash script to achieve the csv to excel.

```
<curl-command>|jq '.results | map(.name), map(.DOB), map(.Enrollmentdate) | @csv' >file.csv
```

I was able to get the output as below

```
smith jones, jacob Mathew, Anita Rodrigues
1992-03-26,  1993-03-26,  1994-03-26
2013-08-24,  2014-10-02,  2015-02-19
```

What i am trying to achieve is as below

```
name:smith jones, name:jacob Mathew, name:Anita Rodrigues
DOB:1992-03-26,  DOB:1993-03-26,  DOB:1994-03-26
Enrollmentdate:2013-08-24,  Enrollmentdate:2014-10-02, Enrollmentdate:2015-02-19
```

Comment: Your JSON is malformed - fix the syntax first and why is `Enrollmentdate` having spaces in one and not in other?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Made necessary edits.

Comment: Your question is still incomplete. The fields `.uri`/`.created`/`.lastDownloaded` are not present in the input JSON

Answer (score 1):

1. Since you want the key names as well as their values, then adapting your approach, you could use the following, in conjunction with the -r command-line option,  to produce CSV:

```
    .results
    | map(to_entries[] | select(.key=="name")),
      map(to_entries[] | select(.key=="DOB")),
      map(to_entries[] | select(.key=="Enrollmentdate"))
    | map("\(.key):\(.value)" )
    | @csv`
```

2. If you want CSV, then stick with the above; if you are confident that quoting the strings
   is never necessary, change `@csv` to `join(", ")`; if you want to remove the quotation
   marks only when they are not necessary, you could add a def for a simple filter to do just that.
3. The repetition of `to_entries` in the above is a bit of an eye-sore.  You might want to think about how to avoid it.

Comment: Thanks a ton! it worked. My humble apologies about the mismatch. For the benefit of everyone i have edited and corrected the command to match with the json data.